# Exception trying to process user input

Tags: java, if-statement, nullpointerexception, return-value

I have three classes, `Main`:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String []args){
    UserData myData = new UserData();
    SolveMath myMath = new SolveMath();
    myMath.findLength();
   }
}
```

`UserData` (gets the user input):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UserData {
private double side1;
private double side2;
private double side3;
private double weight;
public UserData(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter side one:");
    side1 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter side two:");
    side2 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter side three:");
    side3 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter weight:");
    weight = scan.nextDouble();
}

public double getSide1(){
    return side1;
}
public double getSide2(){
    return side2;
}
public double getSide3(){
    return side3;
}
public double getWeight(){
    return weight;
  }
}
```

And `SolveMath` (which so far only tries to find the biggest side):

```
public class SolveMath {
private double length;
UserData userData;

public void findLength(){
    if(userData.getSide1() > userData.getSide2() && userData.getSide1() > userData.getSide3()){
        length = userData.getSide1();
    }else if(userData.getSide2() > userData.getSide1() && userData.getSide2() > userData.getSide3()){
        length = userData.getSide2();
    }else if(userData.getSide3() > userData.getSide1() && userData.getSide3() > userData.getSide2()){
        length = userData.getSide3();
    }
    System.out.println(length);
}
```

}

When I compile I get this error (Note error occurs after all inputs have been given):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at eval.user.data.SolveMath.findLength(SolveMath.java:17)
at drivers.Main.main(Main.java:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Am I missing something when I try to find the biggest side?

Comment: Which line is `SolveMath.java:17`?

Comment: Cause you haven't initialized `UserData` in `solveMath` class

Comment: You have to inject `UserData` in `SolveMath`

Comment: It looks to me like you might be getting the error when you run the program, not when you compile it. There is probably an undefined variable used in line 17 there.

Comment: I think the offending line is not included in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You're not initializing `userData` variable in `SolveMath` class, so this line.-

```
if(userData.getSide1() > userData.getSide2() && userData.getSide1() > userData.getSide3())
```

throws the `NullPointerException` in the first access to `userData`.

You could add a default constructor for `SolveMath` class.-

```
public SolveMath() {
    userData = UserData();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `userData` member in your `SolveMath` instance is `null`, so you get the `NullPointerException`. `main()` needs to tell the `SolveMath` instance, "Here is a `UserData` instance for you to use," and then the `SolveMath` instance needs to use it.

You can do this by adding a constructor argument to `SolveMath`'s constructor, and passing the instance from `main()` as a parameter to the constructor invocation. Then the constructor should store the instance in the member variable you already have.

Answer (score 1):

The `userData` variable in the `SolveMath` class is always `null`, which means you're attempting to call methods on `null`, which is illegal (hence the `NullPointerException`).

You need to make sure that the `userData` field in your `SolveMath` class gets a reference to the `userData` instance from `Main`. One way would be to simply pass it in via the constructor, like so:

```
UserData userData = new UserData();
SolveMath myMath = new SolveMath(userData); // <-- add as parameter here
```

To make this work, you will also need to add a constructor to `SolveMath` that takes a `UserData` parameter:

```
public class SolveMath {

    private UserData userData;

    public SolveMath(UserData userData) {
        // Set the private field to the instance passed in
        this.userData = userData;
    }

    ...
}
```

I would also think about changing your `findLength()` function to check if `userData` is `null` (and possibly throw it's own exception) before attempting to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing UserData instance in SolveMath.

One way would be to pass it through a constructor like below

```
public class SolveMath {
    private double length;
    UserData userData;

    public SolveMath(final UserData userData) {
        this.userData = userData;
    }

    public void findLength(){
        if(userData.getSide1() > userData.getSide2() && userData.getSide1() >             userData.getSide3()){
        length = userData.getSide1();
       }else if(userData.getSide2() > userData.getSide1() && userData.getSide2() >    userData.getSide3()){
        length = userData.getSide2();
       }else if(userData.getSide3() > userData.getSide1() && userData.getSide3() > userData.getSide2()){
        length = userData.getSide3();
    }
    System.out.println(length);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String []args){
        UserData myData = new UserData();
        SolveMath myMath = new SolveMath(myData);
        myMath.findLength();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

UserData is null. You have to pass userData as parameter to solvemath and of course solvemath must have a set function or constructor for passing userdata. You can give default values inside the constructor. So, solvemath must have an additional constructor or a set method. You choose

Comment: but then the user gets prompted to give side lengths how do I avoid that?

Comment: All the other say that userdata is uninitialized. Why am I wrong?

Comment: Because creating another instance of `UserData` using `new` is the wrong solution; there already is one, anyway, and creating it in `SolveMath` would spoil the modularity of the program.